# Sending mkv file over udpsink gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to stream an mkv file over udpsink as an rtp payload, but when the I receive the packets it drops almost every other frame. The stream just freezes for a couple of seconds and then shows the time synced frame. I have a timestamp on the video file and it jumps a the same amount of time it freezes for. The setup is gstreamer is run on a Raspberry Pi 4 and I view the stream using vlc on another computer.

I have the payload working so it sends over the udpsink successfully using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.mkv ! matroskademux ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004
```

I tried changing the buffer size of the udpsink and it had little effect (it might have increased the shown frames a bit).

Comment: Have you tried putting a `h264parse config-interval=1` in front of the `rtph264pay`? I'll mke sure that you'll have the correct SPS/PPS set

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't seem to have an effect